# Is Temiri Blagg (from the last scene of The Last Jedi) an allusion to Mickey's Sorcerer's Apprentice?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, disney

At the end of The Last Jedi, a boy named Temiri Blagg (AKA "Broom Boy") uses the force to [grab a sweeping broom](https://youtu.be/BRSTsD_vrV8?t=68).

[image: Boy uses force to grab broom.]

Instantly, it came to my mind that this scene was an homage to Mickey's *Sorcerer's Apprentice* (since Disney bought Lucasfilm some years earlier).

[image]

What I want to know: **was there any official information, press release, interview, or article, which suggests that the connection is intentional?**

Comment: The name sense to be based on the actor's name, more or less, so it's not a [tuckerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckerization) of anything to do with Mickey or that particular film.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage, I did not suggest the link to Mickey's Sorcerer's Apprentice due to the name. Instead, it's the similarities between the scenes that strikes me. And the fact that Disney owns the whole thing, and so they *could*.

Comment: oh but if, for instance, the lead animator for the sorcerer's apprentice had a similar name it would be a bit of evidence towards your theory it a clue to finding a quote that mentioned the name and the similarities in the scene as a whole.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage, now I understand, so I did a quick search (fandom.com's disney), but none of the credit's names match. I guess that at this point only insider information from The Last Jedi team could salvage my theory, other than that very brief - but, at least to me, meaningful - scene similarity.

Comment: It probably is, they also allude to Mary Poppins in the scene where Leia is blown into space.

Comment: @sf02, nah, Leia has no umbrella on that scene.... While in the Blagg vs. Mickey case we have: two dissatisfied kids with telekinesis powers, on child labour regime, use their powers to help on the sweeping service, and the brooms are very similar too. I can't help thinking Disney has siezed the opportunity to link stories. Don't get surprised if Mickey one day shows up with a lightsaber.